# How to display JSON data (without proper labels) in a table with JS and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have JSON data being parsed to the front-end through Ajax call. The format of the JSON data looks something like this:

```
 { 
   "num_meetings":{ 
      "EOF/TRiO":{ 
         "4 Meetings":1,
         "11 Meetings":1
      },
      "Learning Center":{ 
         "1 Meetings":8,
         "2 Meetings":10,
         "3 Meetings":4,
         "4 Meetings":9,
         "5 Meetings":2,
         "6 Meetings":1,
         "7 Meetings":2,
         "8 Meetings":1,
         "13 Meetings":1
      },
      "Student Success Coach Office":{ 
         "3 Meetings":2,
         "4 Meetings":1
      }
   }
}
```

How would I display this in a table on the front end?

I was attempting to approach this with this snippet:

```
  var tabular = resp.msg.num_meetings;

  var html = "";
  html += "<table class='table small table-responsible-sm table hover table-sm table-stripped'>";
  html += `<tr><th>Location</th><th>Attended</th></tr>`;

  tabular.forEach(function(elem,index) {
    html += `<tr>`;
    html += `<td><b>${elem.???}</b></td>`;
    html += `</tr>`;
  });
  html += "</table>";
  return html;
```

I'm not sure how to access the elements inside num_meetings.

Table can look something like this:

```
----------------------------------
Location   | Meetings | Attendance
----------------------------------
EOF/TRio   | 4 Meetings | 1 
----------------------------------
EOF/TRio   | 11 Meetings | 1
----------------------------------
Learning Center ....
```

Comment: Hi, Try to convert object into array using Object.entries(your_object_name). It might help you to loop over object.

Comment: The comma **❟ ❟ ❟ ❟ ❟ ❟** is your friend, without it your JSON is invalid.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I added how I expect the table to look like. Could you be more specific about the 2nd loop?

Comment: The JSON you provided is invalid, it's missing commas after each value. You can use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate it and give it a proper format.

Comment: @Camilo it should be fixed now sorry, i just copied the format it spit back to me when i console logged the data

Comment: I see the same invalid JSON as before, nothing changed.

Comment: @Camilo I just pasted it in the formatter and it says it's valid. One more shot? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a row (`tr`) for each value of each object inside `"num_meetings"`.

So, to do that, in a simple way, you'll need two loops. I'm looping over `num_meetings` keys, then getting its value and looping over all values inside it. A little confusing, but look the code and I think you'll understand.

```js
var resp = {
  "msg": {
    "num_meetings": {
      "EOF/TRiO": {
        "4 Meetings": 1,
        "11 Meetings": 1
      },
      "Learning Center": {
        "1 Meetings": 8,
        "2 Meetings": 10,
        "3 Meetings": 4,
        "4 Meetings": 9,
        "5 Meetings": 2,
        "6 Meetings": 1,
        "7 Meetings": 2,
        "8 Meetings": 1,
        "13 Meetings": 1
      },
      "Student Success Coach Office": {
        "3 Meetings": 2,
        "4 Meetings": 1
      }
    }
  }
}

//-- let's work with the data now --\\
var tabular = resp.msg.num_meetings;
var html = "";

html += "<table class='table small table-responsible-sm table hover table-sm table stripped'>";
html += "<tr><th>Location</th><th>Meetings</th><th>Attendance</th></tr>";

for (let key in tabular) {
  let obj = tabular[key]

  for (let innerKey in obj) {
    html += `<tr>`;
    html += `<td>${key}</td>`;
    html += `<td>${innerKey}</td>`;
    html += `<td>${obj[innerKey]}</td>`;
    html += `</tr>`;
  }

};

document.body.innerHTML = html
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

`.forEach` won't work here, since `resp.msg.num_meetings` is not an array but an object, thats why I'm using `for..in`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I was stuck on the errors I was getting for using forEach. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: How is yours data sorted automatically? I tried the same method but mine is not sorted at all.

Comment: What? What dou you mean by sorted? It is just following the hard coded data structure from variable `resp`...

Comment: I added a picture of my output to the question. My JSON data is coming in sorted and in the same way you hard coded it but when it's outputting the data it seems to be in random order.

Comment: If it comes from server in correct format, it's weird... but do not mix questions, since your original question is answered and solved it can be used by other people with same problem, so don't edit it to add more questions or change its essence. Open a new question on StackOverflow with your new problem